# Can't parent bones

Tags: armature, parent

I have a bone 'Root' that I want to be the parent of a bone 'BodyCtrl'. I can't parent it though. All the bones are in the same armature and i'm in edit mode, yet I can't create the parent.

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Blend file: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=1909" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/1909/)

Comment: I works fine for me (tested). How are you doing it ?

Comment: It works fine for me too, using Ctrl+P -> Keep Offset. Please specify what exactly doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can select the bone you want parented, go to Properties > Bone settings > relations > Parent, and set the bone you want as a parent there.

[image]

Comment: So silly me. I think I was in the armature tab and not the bone tab.